# Enable textbox inside Repeater through JS function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

My textbox (asp.net) is inside the DIV and panel in a repeater's details section(toggle) 
How can i access the textbox in java script function to make it enable upon click of a link button in the same panel.

```
   <div id='d<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>' class="details">

   <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="195px" BackColor="gray" Font-Bold="False"   ForeColor="Maroon">
  <br />
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="LicenseID"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval   (Container.DataItem,"LicenseID") %>' Enabled="False" BackColor="Gray"  BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox>
```

I tried this way but error is showing

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function MyJSFunction() {
             var tet = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>");

                       }
 </script>
```

but following error message is showing.

> BC30451: 'TextBox1' is not declared

It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

EDIT
 Here is my code in vb.net .But converting to js function i found errors

```
       If e.CommandName = "edit" Then 
       DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("TextBox2"),   TextBox).Enabled = True
       DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("Textbox2"), TextBox).BorderStyle =BorderStyle.NotSet 
       DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("Textbox2"), TextBox).BackColor = Drawing.Color.White       
      end if
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because into the repeater your id becomes yourRepeaterID_TextBox1_Sequence
Use Javascript to ger all inputs. Something like this:

```
  <script>
    function MyJSFunction() {
      var tb = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
      for (var i = 0; i < tb.length; i++) {
        if (tb[i].type != "text") { continue; } // this is not TextBox
        // do whatever
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,I have written the vb.net code for doing the same but to avoid post back i am re writing code. Below is my server side code which i have to rewrite.                                                             If e.CommandName = "edit" Then

      DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("TextBox2"), TextBox).Enabled = True
      DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("Textbox2"), TextBox).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.NotSet
      DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("Textbox2"), TextBox).BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
  end if

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery wtih selector like this:

```
var textBox = $(".details input[type='text'][id*='TextBox1']");
```

Regards,
Uros

Comment: how can i enable the repeater textbox